# Changing line colour in plot based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I'd want to make a graph in which the colours of the many curves they represent change depending on a matching value in a specific column.

The database is presented as follows:

```
row0 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,2,4,6,8,10]}
row1 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,3,9,12,15,18]}
row2 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,4,8,12,16,20]}

row = [row0,row1,row2]

Test = {"Float":[0.5,10.24,25.2], "Funtions": row }


Test_ = pd.DataFrame(data = Test)
```

A column in the Dataframe contains float values.
The second column contains a dataframe with two columns (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame).

Basically, I want to plot the graph in the second column for each row.

I can easily do this in this way:

```
for m in range(len(Test_)):
    Func = (Test_["Funtions"][m])
    plt.plot(Func["A"], Func["B"])
plt.show()
```

I am inserting the result so that it is even clearer.

[image]

At this point, I'd like each of these curve to change colour based on the value of the numerical values column "Float". I would also like to add a colourbar.

I hope I have been clear enough. Thank you for your support.

PS.
Thank you Mr. T for the suggestions. I have asked the question again and added a practical example.

Comment: I think you should provide [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please see also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). There are several possibilities regarding how your data are structured and what the expected output is. And please [don't post images of code/data/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8881141). Post the formatted text directly here on SO.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had hoped that this would make my objective clear. I will try to simplify the problem and post an example with a similar dataframe. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'd like to add a bar as well. Actually, I'm not able to recreate a Dataframe as the one proposed. This dataframe is the result of a little more complicated process. In any case, I should have a column with float values and another with a dataframe for each row.
As a newbie, I'm having difficulty just reproducing a simple example. In any case, I'll try it.

Comment: I have reproduced the question by adding an example. Thanks for your support. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely one of the more ...interesting... dataframe structures I have seen. Not sure how you ended up with that. But this is not the question here, so we import (or construct) a [colormap `my_cmap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#classes-of-colormaps) to map the [normalized `my_norm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html) `Float` values to colors, then use the normalized `my_cmap` to create a [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colorbar-only-py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import cm, colors

#your data
row0 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,2,4,6,8,10]}
row1 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,3,9,12,15,18]}
row2 = {"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0,4,8,12,16,20]}
Test_ = pd.DataFrame({"Float": [0.5,10.24,25.2], "Funtions": [row0,row1,row2]})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

my_cmap = cm.viridis
my_norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=Test_["Float"].min(), vmax=Test_["Float"].max())

for m in range(len(Test_)):
    Func = (Test_["Funtions"][m])
    ax.plot(Func["A"], Func["B"], color=my_cmap(my_norm(Test_["Float"][m])))
    
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=my_norm, cmap=my_cmap), orientation="vertical", label="Float value")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

If you prefer to classify the displayed curves, you can also use a qualitative colormap or create your own [ListedColorMap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps):

```
my_cmap = colors.ListedColormap(["blue", "gold", "red"])
```

[image]